# Переобьявление CSS-свойств

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подключая какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку, например Bootstrap, её CSS-свойства могут не совпасть с требуемыми к определённой странице. Допустим, в сторонней библиотеке написано

```
body {
  font-family: Arial
}
```

но по проекту необходимо использовать

```
body {
  font-family: Times New Roman
}
```

Что правильнее менять, если CSS-свойства библиотеки и родной таблицы стилей страницы конфликтуют? Изменить свойство в библиотеке, или добавить `!important` в родную таблицу стилей?

Comment: у bootstrap есть исходники в sass и less, в которых можно выставить все параметры так как нужно

Answer (score 2):

загрузите CSS файл проекта после библиотек и изменяйте там что и как захотите. Стили определённые позже перезаписывают предыдущие записи. Использовать `!important` или влезать в стили самих библиотек редко когда пригождается

Comment: Просто у нас с коллегой возник спор и хотелось уточнить как, всё-таки, правильнее поступать в таких ситуациях.

Comment: @Prographer лезть в код какой-либо библиотеки, будь она CSS, PHP или DLL - моветон, если конечно не ради патча уязвимости. !important использовать смысла нет, если переопределение работает и без него (пример: http://jsfiddle.net/heptbeu3/) и к тому же !important плохо сказывается на читабильности и может повлечь за собой непонятки.

Answer (score 0):

Если два варианта.
1. !important, при чем important  можно использовать несколько, пример

```
.p{ 
   font-family: Times New Roman!important!important; /*но это не желательно*/
}
```

2. Без important. Вместо important можно задавать блоки родительских элементов.
Пример:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p class="p">Текст пример...</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

в CSS:

```
ul li .p{
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

т.е. можете хоть html и body указывать.